# 554 Transaction failed: Empty address with Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp

When I connect directly to SES:

application -> amazon SES

I get this error.

However, if i use Postfix:

application -> postfix (satelite system) -> Amazon SES.

Everything works.

After turning on SMTP debugging, I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, my app was setting an invalid SMTP header.

> Return-Path: <>

When this is sent to postfix, postfix did not relay this to Amazon SES.

When this was sent directly to Amazon SES, the error appears.

> 554 Transaction failed: Empty address

I was able to solve this by not setting the Return-Path header at all. Amazon SES will figure it out set the header with a proper value.

I think if you set it to a valid email address that has been verified with your Amazon SES account, it might work (I did not try that).

Comment: Thank you! this came in handy 7 years later. Can you please share how you figured out the mischievous header?